# Intellij IDEA shortcuts vs Eclipse shortcuts

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, shortcut

I'm starting to use Intellij IDEA and it's taking some time to get used to the shortcuts, especially coming from years using Eclipse.

I don't know whether the IDEA shortcuts were specially designed for a better experience using it. For that reason, my question:

Is it worth investing some time learning the Intellij IDEA shortcuts or just using Eclipse shortcuts is enough?

Comment: Yes, it is.  Know your tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As this blog article says: [Don't bring your shortcuts with you](http://hadihariri.com/2015/06/10/dont-bring-your-shortcuts/)

Answer (score 1):

It is better to spend some time to learn Intellij IDEA shortcuts if you decide to use Intellij IDEA for your work, because most of the shortcuts differ from Eclipse.

Shortcut Example :

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> -->

- (Eclipse) Create new project using the Wizard.
- (Intellij IDEA) To quickly open any class.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> -->

- (Eclipse) Close current file
- (Intellij IDEA) Select successively increasing code blocks

Action Example :

- Run : (Eclipse) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>  ; (Intellij IDEA) <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>
- Debug :(Eclipse) <kbd>F11</kbd> ;
      (Intellij IDEA) <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>

More shortcuts for [Eclipse](http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Eclipse.html) and [Intellij IDEA](http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/IntelliJ.html#link_4)

Answer (score 0):

you can create and customize your own keymap (your own shortcuts).  there is an excellent plugin that can help: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6827?pr=

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use IntelliJ you might as well invest the time to get used to the shortcut key differences. You'll probably want to spend some time getting familiar with the IDE too, and see how things are done differently, and other things like plugins that might be useful for you. I would recommend watching the series of short videos at 2X speed to get you familiar quickly: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/